# Tennis tiebreak in doubles

Tags: rules, tennis, tie-breaker

What are the rules for a tiebreak in doubles tennis, particularly with service? What are the similarities and differences between a doubles tiebreak and a singles tiebreak?

Answer (score 2):

In a doubles tie-break the first point is served by the player whose turn it is to serve. The following two points shall be served by the player (of the opposing team) due to serve next. After than (starting with the first team), each team's player whose turn it is to serve next, serves alternately for two consecutive points until the end of the tie-break.

> TIE-BREAK GAME
>
> During a tie-break game, points are scored “Zero”, “1”, “2”, “3”, etc. The first player/team to win seven points wins the “Game” and “Set”, provided there is a margin of two points over the opponent(s). If necessary, the tie-break game shall continue until this margin is achieved.
>
> The player whose turn it is to serve shall serve the first point of the tie-break game. The following two points shall be served by the opponent(s) (in doubles, the player of the opposing team due to serve next). After this, each player/team shall serve alternately for two consecutive points until the end of the tie-break game (in doubles, the rotation of service within each team shall continue in the same order as during that set).
>
> The player/team whose turn it was to serve first in the tie-break game shall be
>   the receiver in the first game of the following set.

One of the differences is that in doubles a match tie-break is normally used to replace the final set.

> MATCH TIE-BREAK (SUPER TIE-BREAK)
>
> When the score in a match is one set all, or two sets all in best of five sets
>   matches, one tie-break game shall be played to decide the match. This tie-break
>   game replaces the deciding final set.
>   The player/team who first wins ten (or seven) points shall win this match tie-break and
>   the match provided there is a margin of two points over the opponent(s).
>
> Note: When using the match tie-break to replace the final set:
>   • the original order of service continues. (Rules 5 and 14)
>   • in doubles, the order of serving and receiving within the team may be altered,
>   as in the beginning of each set. (Rules 14 and 15)
>   • before the start of the match tie-break there shall be a 120 seconds set break.
>   • balls should not be changed before the start of the match tie-break even if a
>   ball change is due.

https://www.itftennis.com/media/298557/298557.pdf